# restrictions of analytic functions to the circle

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, analytic-functions, hardy-spaces

This seems really simple, but since I didn't find it written anywhere I wanted to make sure I'm not crazy and/or get a reference to a standard textbook where this fact appears.

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be analytic on a disc of radius $R>1$ around the origin. Let $\varphi:S^1 \to \mathbb{C}$ be the restriction of $f$ to the unit circle. Then the negative-index Fourier coefficients of $\varphi$ all vanish.

My idea of a proof: write $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n\geq 0} a_n z^n$. The restriction of that series on the circle is the Fourier series of $\varphi$.

*comment* - I know that the converse of this statement is not true and that's one way to characterize Hardy spaces. My motivation here is just to see that this direction is easy.

Comment: Your reasoning is fine. The conclusion holds also   if $f$ is analytic in the open unit disc and continuous on the closed unit disc.